# Use navigation drawer in all of my layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, fragment, navigation-drawer

In android app, I want to use navigation drawer in all of my layouts , i cant use all of my fragments and keep changing them just in 1 activity . So how should i implement navigation drawer in all of my activities ?

Comment: have you tried anything/ or what's your exact problem?

Comment: yes i made a parent activity of navigation drawer , and extended it to all other activities , and included the xml of main drawer in all other activities . Its working fine but i have to invisible the layout of other activities while opening the navigation drawer .

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can use drawer in all of your screens. Use one activity and add/replace fragments required in/at content layout below.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- Content layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_frame_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
    <!-- Toolbar layout -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/action_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/search_theme" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/action_bar"
            android:background="@drawable/dropshadow" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
<!-- Drawer menu item layout -->
<include layout="@layout/layout_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: thats the problem , only making 1 activity can make app more uneasy to develop . and its ok if we have 4,5 activities , but many a times we are needed to make more activities , in that case what should we do ?

Answer (score 0):

that is not possible but you can use activity for that

in your code :

```
     @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.nav_search) {

                // Handle the search action
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_home)
     {
                //handle the home option
                Intent homeIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a single parent activity.. and have a drawer in it... and for rest of activities have fragments... this approach will let you have navigation drawer in all screens of your app

Comment: means if i create n activities , i should define the content in fragments and not in content_main or activity main ?

Comment: Have a single class which extends activity and for all the other screens you can have class which extends fragments... Then you can have a fragment manager and make fragment transactions in your class that extends activity....

Comment: Also you can read about fragment manager, Fragment transactions to get the implementation... Since you will have drawer in your activity all your frgamnts(all other screens) will also have drawer